# Apache appends trailing slash to my rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have clean path with the same name as existing directory.

I use these .htaccess rules to support clean path for the path:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

everything works correctly (I have a "mydir" clean path working and I can access existing files in the /mydir directory directly), but apache appends the trailing slash all the time to requests.
I request `http://domain.com/mydir`, and it redirects me `301` to `http://domain.com/mydir/`.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing slash after `/mydir/` is added by an Apache module called `mod_dir` that adds a trailing slash after all the directories. This is due to this setting turned on by default:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

You can turn it off using:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However it might expose some directories by showing their listings.

[**Security Warning**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information
>   disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active
>   (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say,
>   index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL.
>   In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html
>   file. But a request without trailing slash would list the directory
>   contents.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's proper URL always ends in a slash `/`. Because it treats URL's as if they were a disk file path (which always ends in a slash). If it's not there, the server needs to take one additional step to internally add it. I say let it be.

Plus Google (supposedly) likes the trailing slashes.

I say keep it as is.

Please read more: http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/

and here: http://bit.ly/1uSvbfy :)

Comment: I use Drupal and all auto generated paths don't have trailing slashes. The problem is with this one, which causes some strange issue in ajax requests because of the trailing slash.

Comment: Your comment really is a completely different question :) But, though the browser doesn't show it, the trailing slash is always `301`ed